# File upload in PHP giving error

Tags: php

I am building an web app using PHP.I am creating a file upload section in it but i am having problem.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=    "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been    uploaded.";
 } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
  }
  ?>
```

It is working fine for images. but when i try to check what happens if i upload mp4 file. it echo File already exists,Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. Kindly guide me where i am doing mistake so that this work fine for me without having errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its  because there is a restriction on your php file

Comment: @Amit Thakur it also show file already exists. Y?

Comment: Are you sure the file you are a upload doesnt already exist in dir?

Comment: yes, plz copy this code and check on your localhost. Thanks

Comment: it is [working](https://eval.in/298954) fine
for me after a few modifications===>

Comment: @Amit Thakur kindly post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is working fine for images. but when i try to check what happens if
>   i upload mp4 file. it echo Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed

This is limitation simply because your code limits it as such.

```
// Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=    "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

If the file is not of `jpg`, `png`, `jpeg`, or `gif` it won't allow the upload.

> It echoes file already exists

This is simply because the file is already there (wherever the directory is), due to this check:

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

> Sorry, there was an error uploading your file

I cannot see why this is. Your conditional `if ($uploadOk == 0)` is set to 0 in all of your other conditionals, and so should be true and should echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded".

Moving to comments to ask.

Comment: &James i know i have restrict this code but it echo file already exits with Sorry only ...........are allowed. I want to have only error instead of file already exits + error

Comment: Right above this comment in your code: `// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error` put this and tell me the result: `echo $uploadOk; exit;`

Comment: i am getting this error: File is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, file already exists.0

Answer (score 1):

Because you have condition that disallow other extensions, so it works according to the code:

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=    "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

And apparently you already have such file in your target folder. Check it again.

Comment: i know i have restrict this code but it echo file already exits with Sorry only ...........are allowed. I want to have only error instead of file already exits + error

Comment: are you use same name for the files?

Answer (score 0):

> HTML Code

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="tags" type="file" name="employer_image"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form
```

> UPLOAD.PHP

```
if (isset( $_POST['submit'] )
{
 function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
  {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }

      }
   if (!empty($_FILES["employer_image"]["name"])) {
   $file_name=$_FILES["employer_image"]["name"];
   $temp_name=$_FILES["employer_image"]["tmp_name"];
   $imgtype=$_FILES["employer_image"]["type"];
   $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
   $imagename=date("d-m-Y").'-'.time().$ext;
   $target_path = "folder-path".$imagename;
  if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
           /* write insert query for store in mysql*/
   }else{
   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
   } 
  }
}
```

> first select file form your local after on click submit button 
>   it's redirect to upload.php file there are first function are white that find the extension for file and it's return your file extension 
>   you need to create a folder (where you can store with name)
>   after extension code it's get the file name with dateand time and you can set target path of file where you save images and run your insert query after that.
>   First you check the folder permission where you can move files

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: We are Updated it with description

Answer (score 0):

check file extensions case. And allow both upper and lower cases.

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=    "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType !=    "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "GIF" )